# Chain rule for fractional laplacian

Tags: real-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes

Does anyone know a formula of chain rule for fractional laplacian?
say we take the fractional laplacian of order a on function $g(U(x))$  $x\in \mathbb{R}^2$, $U \in \mathbb{R}$, $g \colon \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ functional.

Thanks

Comment: Is fractional laplacian a fractional derivative or Reisz transorm? 

Comment: Reisz transform( I thought this definition will be consistent with analytical operator theory)

Comment: I would begin by looking for analogues of the product rule. Once you have that, then the chain rule for the case where $g$ is a polynomial will follow, giving some insight into the general situation. 

Answer (score 7):

In the fractional case, it turns out that *approximate*  chain rules are more useful than exact formulae (at least for applications to the analysis of PDE).  See

http://wiki.math.toronto.edu/TorontoMathWiki/index.php/Fractional_Derivative

In the case $0 \leq a \leq 1/2$, the rule roughly takes the form

$$ (-\Delta)^a g(U) \approx ((-\Delta^a) U) \cdot \nabla g(U) + \ldots$$

where the $\ldots$ error is a paraproduct which is "lower order" than the main term in some sense.  One popular way to make this formula precise is the *Bony linearisation formula,* originally developed in http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=631751 .   This is part of a more general theory known as *paradifferential calculus,* discussed for instance in Taylor's book http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1766415

Comment: Is there a good bound for the case $1/2 < a < 1$? Supposing that $g$ is a smooth function.

Answer (score 0):

I showed that the Riesz potential is an integral formulation of general fractional two-side derivative, that is much more general in the sense that is valid for any order greater than -1 for a broad class of funtions. 
I can give copies by sending a mail to mdo@fct.unl.pt